# Height of ContentDialog in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

How do I specify the height of ContentDialog in UWP app?

On the phone it extends almost entire page even of the dialog content height is third of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy. Do it in XAML:

```
        <ContentDialog x:Name="MyContentDialog" Height="100" Width="150"
                    Title="Lorem Ipsum"
                    PrimaryButtonText="OK" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="True">
        <StackPanel Width="150" Height="100">
            <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentDialog>
```

Or use MaxHeight attribute.
Here is good link [Windows 10 XAML Tips: MessageDialog and ContentDialog](http://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2015/windows-10-xaml-tips-messagedialog-and-contentdialog)

If you have too much content - you can try place [ScrollViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) inside ContentDialog or update [ContentDialog default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx)

Comment: The problem with fixed height is that it depends on width which is also difficult to set fixed wince it is affected by the device width. Is there way to set the ContentDialog height to the height of the control it hosts?